# Does Android 6.0 Changes affects previously published apps (Targeted API lower than 23)

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

According to [Android M Changes page](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html), there is a new platform changes for Android 6.0. and they saying that

> If you have previously published an app for Android, be aware that these changes in the platform affect your app.

So if my app is previously released before `Android M` release, and my app targeting `API 21`

1- Does this new changes will affect it?

2-Does i have to update my code to follow this new changes to be compatible with `Android M`and raise the `API Level` to be `23`?

** take in consideration in [Android developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html#fc) they says

> If the API level of the platform is higher than the version declared by your app's targetSdkVersion, the system may enable compatibility behaviors to ensure that your app continues to work the way you expect.

Does this forward compatibility is applied to the `Android M changes` or not?

** i know this is a foolish version and i am daft man but please i need a help.

Comment: http://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/things-you-need-to-know-about-android-m-permission-developer-edition/en

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this new changes will affect it?

Some will. For example, while all of your permissions that you request in the manifest will be granted at install time (as they used to), the user can go in and deny them to your app in Settings. However, usually, all this will do is block access to data from your app, in ways that you should be handling already. For example, you might ask for `READ_CONTACTS` and query `ContactsContract`, but you should be handling the case where the user has no contacts. On Android 6.0, you might get no contacts in response to your query because the user denied your app access to contacts.

> Does i have to update my code to follow this new changes to be compatible with Android Mand raise the API Level to be 23?

Generally speaking, no. Older Android apps usually work fine on Android 6.0.

However, eventually, there will be something that you want to have that requires `targetSdkVersion` of 23 or higher, in which case you will need to take other changes into account, such as the runtime permissions. And, you will need to test your app on Android 6.0, to see if Android 6.0's changes trigger bugs in your code.

Comment: In the Android M changes they have mentioned the new changes like (Doze and App standby) does this affects the apps targets APIs lower than 23 ?

Does 'Access to Hardware Identifier' affects it also ?

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu: Doze and app standby definitely affect apps with any `targetSdkVersion`. I have not researched the hardware identifier issue.

Comment: Another question: They have said that they have removed `Notification.setLatestEventInfo()` so if application with target API level lower than 23 and uses  `Notification.setLatestEventInfo()` what will happen ? the documentation doesn't explain what will happen shall i have to test and explore myself ? or there are more detailed documentation?

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu: It is removed from the SDK. The method still exists on the device. It is merely marked with the `@hide` annotation in the API 23 SDK. Apps that call that method will continue to work, at least for a while. However, since that method had been deprecated for about four years, few apps should be using anymore anyway.

Comment: U mean if the application targets API lower than 23 (uses `Notification.setLatestEventInfo()` ) and this app installed on device that have Android M , this app will work normally ?

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu: I mean if the application "targets" any API level, and the application is installed on an Android 6.0 device, the app will work normally. If the `compileSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, it will fail to compile. If the `compileSdkVersion` is 14(?) through 22, it will compile with warnings due to the deprecated method.

Comment: Okay i got what u say, u mean the function exists  on SDK 23 and marked with @hide annotation to enable the applications previously published with api lower than 23 to run on it ?

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu: Correct. This is not something that Google usually does. Usually, they settle for leaving the method (or class or field or whatever) as deprecated. I do not know why they elected to hide this one. However, again, developers have been encouraged, for quite some time, to stop using this method, and so hopefully relatively few currently-maintained apps still use it.

Comment: Okay, why what u have said isn't mentioned obviously on the Documentation ? If i want to ensure that my app that targets api lower than 23 will run normally on Android M what shall i do ? because the documentation isn't clear.

Comment: @MohamedHatemAbdu: "why what u have said isn't mentioned obviously on the Documentation ?" -- ask Google. "If i want to ensure that my app that targets api lower than 23 will run normally on Android M what shall i do ?" -- test your app.